# How to add PostCSS PreCSS plugin to project

Tags: npm, package.json, postcss

I am new in PostCSS and I don't know, how to add [preCSS](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss) plugin. Basically, I am using Tailwind, where is recommend PostCSS. But till today, I always used Sass in my projects. With this preCSS plugin, I can use Sass syntax - that's the goal.

My packagake.json

```
{
  "name": "zs-skalova-layout-only",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "tailwind.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "postcss css/tailwind.css -o tailwind-compil.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "precss": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

and here is my postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    precss: {},
  }
}
```

No Webpack, Gulp or etc. solutions please.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which framework are you using, Vue.js?

Comment: I have the same problem. I use React+Tailwind